# Slim framework vs Silex framework

Tags: php, frameworks, slim, silex

I'm trying to choose a PHP framework for my next project. I have narrowed down the list to Slim and Silex (I don't like the full stack bloated frameworks, I prefer to add only what I need and nothing else).

I think Silex produces a bit uglier code than Slim, but I'm afraid to choose Slim because it's changing constantly and I will be stuck with the current version if it breaks backward compatibility. Also Silex is based on battle-tested Symfony components.

Which one is easier to understand? Which one is more beginner friendly? Do you have any bad experience with them?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: And why is it bad to hear other people's opinion?

Comment: It's not bad per se. it's just not what SO is about.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to recommend anything, in fact I'll make it even more complicated by adding [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) and a [clarification](http://www.slimframework.com/2015/04/14/lumen.html) on how they position themselves.

That being said, what I actually want to tackle is the following statement:

> I'm afraid to choose Slim because it's changing constantly and I will
>   be stuck with the current version if it breaks backward compatibility

This is a Schrodinger's statement ... true but also false.
If you look at the project's history you'll see about the same rate of change (~2 years) as **every** other framework out there. Even the 'LTS' versions of Symfony and Laravel have 2-3 years.

So I'd say that's a non-issue and you should pick whatever feels more natural to you and more productive. But do take into account the entire ecosystem of tools that you'll need (DB interaction, form handling, templating, etc...)